# why my code which includes hashfunction and unordered_set uncompilable?

Tags: hash, compilation, unordered-set

```
#include <iostream>
#include <string>
#include <unordered_set>
using namespace std;

struct hashfunction{
  size_t operator()(pair<string,int> x){
    size_t ret=5381;
    for(int i=0;i<x.first.length();i++){
       ret=(ret<<5)+(ret)+x.first[i]; 
    }
    ret+=x.second;
    return ret;
  }
};

unordered_set<pair<string,int>,hashfunction> myset;


int main(void)
{
  string a="123";
  int b= 4;
  myset.insert({a,b});
  
}
```

I am studying unordered_set and hashfunction. But the code above is not compilable. why not? Anyone can explain why it is not compilable and how to solve this problem?

Answer (score 0):

const is needed after operator()(pair<string,int> x).